# Updating Data Model with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

On the View load, I want to update the favorite value of the `ImageDataModel` according to Firebase Realtime Database.

```
//ImageDataModel.swift

struct ImageDataModel {
    var image: String
    var title: String
    var favorite: String
}

extension ImageDataModel {
    static var data: [ImageDataModel] = [
        ImageDataModel(image: "image_1", title: "XXXXX", favorite: "N"),
        ImageDataModel(image: "image_2", title: "YYYYY", favorite: "N"),
        ImageDataModel(image: "image_3", title: "ZZZZZ", favorite: "N")
    ]
}
```

**Initial View**

```
struct ImageStepView: View {

var data: ImageDataModel
var ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()
var userID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        ...
    }.onAppear { self.getFavoriteImages() }
}

func getFavoriteImages(){
    
    ref.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        print("value::",value ?? "") // value:: {"image_1" = "Y"; "image_3" = "Y";}

        //Here I want to update the ImageDataModel 
        
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}
```

For example, If Firebase returned value contains `{"image_1" = "Y"; "image_3" = "Y";}` than I want to update my `ImageDataModel` like this:

```
extension ImageDataModel {
        static var data: [ImageDataModel] = [
            ImageDataModel(image: "image_1", title: "XXXXX", favorite: "Y"),
            ImageDataModel(image: "image_2", title: "YYYYY", favorite: "N"),
            ImageDataModel(image: "image_3", title: "ZZZZZ", favorite: "Y")
        ]
    }
```

//Firebase Data Structure Example

```
{
  "A9E41390-7557-4FE3-A319-B4472048AF94" : {
    "image_1" : "Y",
    "image_3" : "Y"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach but I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is that you're having implement this. But it may help if you edit your question to show the JSON at `/users/$userID` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have edited the question. My actual need is manipulating the `ImageDataModel`. Changing `favorite` value for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a list of child nodes under each user ID. You'll want to in that case loop over `snapshot.children` to get each child node as a `DataSnapshot`.

```
ref.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        let childKey = child.key
        let childValue = child.value as! String

        let model = ImageDataModel(image: childKey, title: "???", favorite: childValue)

        ...
    }
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I get all the data I need and construct a new `Data Model` with the help of your answer. Problem is I cannot update the existing `ImageDataModel`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what that means, so can't help with it. If you have an existing list of  `ImageDataModel` objects somewhere, you'll need to find the corresponding object there and either update it or replace it with the new one that is constructed from the data in Firebase. But that sounds like a pure Swift problem, instead of a Firebase one, so I'd recommend searching on "updating an item in an array in swift" to see if that shows good results.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your answer definitely helped me a lot.